# Forcing in $SEARC$

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, forcing

ncatlab, in its entry for $SEAR$ (https://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR), states that

> $SEARC$ ($SEAR$ augmented by an axiom of choice)...is strongly equivalent to $ZFC$.

Since for $SEAR$ (and $SEARC$, according to the ncatlab entry),

> The elements of a set have no "internal structure"; they are merely featureless points,

I would be interested in finding out how one would define notions of forcing in $SEARC$ and how one would (for example) add a Cohen real, or a
Random real.

Also, any references to forcing in SEARC would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sheaves! https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+sheaves (One still needs a generic point to make the model well-pointed, but that can be circumvented the same way generic filters can be avoided in set theory.)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  I thought sheaves played an integral part--thanks for bringing that up!  Regarding sheaves, however (at the risk of sounding stupid and possibly losing points), how (for example) does one define the notion of coverage for sets of featureless points (if I understand correctly, one needs the notion of _coverage_ to define a presheaf in order to define the notion of a sheaf)?  I am wondering whether the definition of sheaf is more suited to a material set theory than a structural set theory like $SEARC$.  Also define the notion of 'generic point' for models of $SEARC$.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais:  Would it be possible to expand your comment into an answer that would address the concerns I had in my previous comment and answer the specific points mentioned in my question?  I would certainly accept such an answer (from you or anyone else as well).

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin sheaves work in any structural set theory, because they work using any base topos.

Comment: More precisely, the notion of Lawvere-Tierney topology makes no references to coverages and sieves, and one can define the double negation topology (which you need for forcing in classical logic) using an LT topology. Getting the appropriate poset of forcing conditions works as in material set theory, (eg the set parameterising partial functions N --> {0,1} with finite domain), changing only a little to work in a structural setting.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  Those are great comments!  If you would expand these comments into an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I fixed the link in your question (it was missing an `nlab/`), and expanded my answer. I hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sheaves work in any structural set theory, because they work using any base topos. Note that SEAR-sets form a well-pointed boolean topos $\mathbf{Set}_{SEAR}$ ([this](https://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR#heyting) Theorem and [this](https://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR#topos) Theorem on the nLab page on SEAR), and SEARC-sets form a well-pointed boolean topos $\mathbf{Set}_{SEARC}$ satisfying the axiom of choice in the form "all surjections have a section". By [Axiom 4](https://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR#infinity) both these variants have natural number objects, denoted $\mathbb{N}$.

The poset $P$ used to add an $A$-indexed collection of Cohen reals is just the set of partial functions $\mathbb{N}\times A \rightharpoonup 1 \amalg 1 =: 2$ (which is in fact definable in any topos with NNO) together with the usual partial ordering. Note that once one has a well-pointed topos with NNO then any "structural" construction one might undertake in ZFC that doesn't rely on Replacement can be done. By this I mean anything not referring to elements of elements of sets and so on, or in other words, things invariant under bijections.

One can define the topos of sheaves on $P$ considered as a site with the double negation topology (which is a special case of the [dense topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dense+topology) on a small category) in a way that only uses the topos-theoretic machinery that $\mathbf{Set}_{SEAR(C)}$ being a topos affords.

In fact the construction in [this section](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuum+hypothesis#unprovability), illustrating the method of forcing as applied to showing CH is not provable from the axioms for a well-pointed boolean topos, works verbatim in SEAR with some minor syntactic sugar for the topos structure (one could unwind it back to the language of SEAR if desired).

Alternatively, the notion of Lawvere-Tierney topology makes no references to coverages and sieves, and one can define the [double negation topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+negation#in_topos_theory) (which you need for forcing in classical logic) using an LT topology. This means one can consider the category of presheaves on $P$, which is nice to consider as [a construction using internal diagrams](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+diagram), and then carve out the subtopos of double negation sheaves.

A good reference is either Tierney's classic paper [Sheaf theory and the continuum hypothesis](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=WwmuvwoAAAAJ&citation_for_view=WwmuvwoAAAAJ:u-x6o8ySG0sC), or if you can get access to it, Mac Lane and Moerdijk's book [Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Sheaves+in+Geometry+and+Logic), the chapter on forcing there is pretty good.

Regarding forcing a random real, one can define the poset of Borel subsets of positive measure in $\mathbb{R}$, because one can define all the relevant machinery in a well-pointed boolean topos with NNO and Choice, and then consider the topos of sheaves with the double-negation topology as before. The point about forcing in ZFC is that it is secretly taking sheaves on a poset and then translating back to ZFC in the internal logic of the sheaf topos using the standard Mitchell-Cole-Osius construction.

---

Regarding Lawvere's comments (in [Foundations and Applications: Axiomatization and Education](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3094791)_) on $L$-sets (for the constructible universe $L$), I'm not sure I agree with that. I think the sets in $L$ are in fact highly structured (even more so than those in the cumulative hierarchy of material set theory generally!). The quote I think you mean is this

> Now Gödel's "constructible" sets L in themselves have a tremendous amount of structure, but the relevant category derived from them is, remarkably, in general much more constant (structureless!) than that devised from an original ambient model V. [page 223]

Note that this follows after Lawvere's reformulation of Cantor's continuum hypothesis as

> for a topos $\mathcal{E}$ of sufficiently structureless sets, CH is true in $\mathcal{E}$ [page 220]

But I don't see that just because CH holds in $L$, we must have that $L$-sets are sufficiently structureless. One could consider that the universe of sets is of the form $L[G]$ (or rather, the topos of sheaves over $L$-sets), but this is a rather specific set-theoretic axiom and I don't know if there are results that say $V$ is a class forcing of its $L$ (this would be very cool if it were the case!) All I can say is: I really don't know what he was on about there.

From where I stand, structural set theory so far lacks an analogue of [inner model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model_theory) of which $L$ is but one example. For a given topos $\mathcal{E}$ These would be toposes $\mathcal{L}$ equipped with a functor $\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{E}$ (*not* a [geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+morphism#definition), *or* a [logical functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor)), but presumably finite-limit-preserving, fully faithful, and probably a few other things (eg structural constructions in ZFC that are absolute). Note that these are *not* internal categories, since they should be as "tall" as the ambient topos. I have no idea how one would actually construct such a topos corresponding to $L$, except by constructing a model of ZFC from the (boolean etc) topos, forming $L$, and then taking its category of sets, and then relying on the [material-structural adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material-structural%20adjunction) to get the faithful functor of interest.

Comment: Thanks.  In the expansion of your answer, could you touch on the role of sheaves  adding 'greater structure' to categories of sets (I am thinking of Wm. Lawvere's paper "Foundations and Applications[,] Axiomatization and Education", Section 5, "How Constant is Constant?",  where he states the following thesis:  "For a topos $\mathscr E$ of sufficiently structureless sets, $CH$ is true in $\mathscr E$", and then claims that the sets in the constructible universe $L$ are "sufficiently structureless")?  That would be great (again, thanks)!

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with LT-topologies, there's no need to invoke them in this context; coverages and sieves also make perfect sense in structural set theory and in any base topos.

Comment: @MikeShulman I agree. But I wanted to mention them because they do away with needing to invoke coverages, to which the OP was mildly objecting.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I can try. I'm not sure I agree with that statement about 'sufficiently structureless sets'. I thinks the sets in $L$ are in fact highly structured (even more so than those in the cumulative hierarchy of material set theory generally!), but I've not read that paper, so I'll dig it out and see what I make of it.

Comment: Ah, here's a better quote from Lawvere: _Now Gödel's "constructible" sets L in themselves have a tremendous amount of structure, but the relevant category derived from them is, remarkably, in general much more constant (structureless!) than that devised from an original ambient model V_ (pg 223). More in my edited answer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  My comment was a (possibly bad) paraphrase of that same quote.  What would be interesting to see is in what sense $\mathscr P$($\omega$) when $CH$ fails is 'less constant' (more structured?) than $\mathscr P_{L}$($\omega$)  in $SEARC$.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin FWIW, I am not convinced by Lawvere's argument that sets with CH are "more constant" than sets without CH.  Regarding $L$, it may be worth noting that there is a faithful forgetful functor $\mathrm{Set}(L) \to \mathrm{Set}(V)$ but not the other way around, so that from the (category-theoretic!) perspective of [stuff, structure, property](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property) the objects of $\mathrm{Set}(L)$ can also be regarded as "sets with structure".

Comment: @MikeShulman:  I was reading through "stuff, structure, property"  and needed to check something.  Would the 'stuff' of a set be the underlying abstract set (Cantor's 'lauter Einsen')?

Comment: The SSP only makes sense with respect to a given forgetful functor.  The identity functor of Set is an equivalence, so it forgets nothing.  If by "a set" you mean a ZF-style set with global $\in$ predicate, then in order to talk about its stuff/structure/property you need a category of them and a forgetful functor.  One possibility is the category of subset-inclusions and the forgetful functor to Set (the category of sets and arbitrary functions); this is faithful but not full, so it forgets structure, i.e. the $\in$-structure of a ZF-set is "structure".

Comment: @DavidRoberts:  Your adjusted answer makes quite a bit of sense.  It satisfies my requirements nicely.  Thanks.  Regarding whether $V$ is a class-forcing extension of its $L$, one might be able to consistently (?) add this as an axiom to the axioms of $ZFC$.  It would be interesting to study the consequences of adding such an axiom.  Regarding Lawvere's reformulation of the continuum hypothesis, is there a precise category-theoretic definition of the term "sufficiently structureless" for a topos $\mathscr E$?  Also, is there a precise notion of 'degree of structure' for category theory?

Comment: The term "sufficiently structureless" should read "sufficiently structureless set".  Also, the phrase 'degree of structure' should read 'degree of structure of a set'.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I don't think so. Lawvere is comparing a base toposes of sets to toposes of structured sets, which was developed in his work on axiomatic cohesion, and he also likes to contrast Cantor's Mengen and Kardinalen, the latter he argues are structural sets, and the former structured sets (like well-ordered sets of reals). There is a forgetful functor from the former to the latter. But this doesn't quite line up with modern practice, so it's more of a philosophical argument, not to mention Cantor wasn't working in a formal system.